# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable: @Environment conforming to protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
protocol CarItem: AnyObject, Observable {
    var carName:String { get }
}


struct CarViewUIKRepresented: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(CarItem.self) var item // <<<<< ERROR: No exact matches in call to initializer 
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CarUIView {
        let carView = CarUIView()
        carView.setupWith(car:item)
        return carView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CarUIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}

class CarUIView : UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupWith<T:CarItem>(car:T) {
        ///
    }
    
}
```

I would like to be able to pass in the environment a model that conforms to the `CarItem` protocol. I am not sure if that is possible and if so how to accomplish that.

Is there a way to pass in the environment a model that adopts protocol `CarItem` and use it in UIViewRepresentable as a generic?

Comment: don't forget to implement `updateUIView` to set the changed item on the carView.

Comment: Yes, I was mainly focusing on the generic setup in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a generic on `CarViewUIKRepresented` :

```
struct CarViewUIKRepresented<T: CarItem>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(T.self) var item
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CarUIView {
        let carView = CarUIView()
        carView.setupWith(car:item)
        return carView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CarUIView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```